# Oracle 11g: what is the best partitioning strategy for a table oriented by effective date?

Tags: oracle11g, database-partitioning

I'm designing a table for storing records by their effective date, something similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE documents
(
  id                            NUMBER(20,0) NOT NULL,
  effective_date_from           DATE         NOT NULL,
  effective_date_to             DATE         NULL,
  documentdata                  BLOB         NOT NULL
)
```

The main type of query done over this table is selecting all records valid for a given effective date:

```
select documentdata from documents where effective_date_from <= '28JUL2015' and (effective_date_to is null or effective_date_to > '28JUL2015')
```

As you can see, the column effective_date_to can be NULL. When a document is first created, its effective_date_to is not known. Only later on, the application is notified that the document is not valid anymore and can therefore update the effective_date_to.

Most of the documents have their effective_date_to updated from one to three months following their creation, but a few of them can take years to be updated.

I estimated that while only 20-30% of the documents will have their effective_date_to NULL in a certain point in time, they will be subject of 80% of the queries. In other words, most of the queries use a very recent effective date.

The cardinality of this table is in the order of millions. Between 150M and 300M items are expect to be stored.

I'm trying to find what would be the best partitioning (and indexing) strategy for such a table, considering that my main goal is to improve the performance of the above query.

My first thought was using RANGE partitions based on the effective_date_to, so that the partitions corresponding to "old" records are not looked for (thanks to partition pruning).

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (effective_date_to) (
PARTITION t1p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2015-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
PARTITION t1p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2015-06-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
PARTITION t1p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2015-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
...
PARTITION t1pN VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

But since the effective_date_to changes from NULL to something else after some months, the records would be probably moved from partitions, potentially resulting in fragmentation.
On the other hand, using other information such as effective_date_from will probably not have the same benefits, as all partitions would need to be looked for.

I would like to know if I'm in the right direction in my partitioning strategy, or if another one should be used.

Note 1: instead setting the effective_date_to to NULL it is acceptable to set it to a date very far in the future. In fact, this is what I'm doing in my current prototype.

Note 2: unfortunately I don't have Oracle 12c, so I cannot use the [Temporal Validity](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/ilm/temporal/temporal.html) feature.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wedded to the basic table design?  It sounds like it would be more efficient from a query perspective to have a `document` table and a `document_validity` table partitioned by `effective_date` where a row was inserted for every day a document was valid.  Retrieving all documents that were effective on a particular day would full scan a partition of `document_validity` and then join to the `document` table to get the `blob`.

Comment: The table design could be changed if if it would result in a performance gain.

Comment: However, one requirement I did not mentioned is that in some seldom cases, I would need to repopulate the table from scratch. In such cases, I would need to re-calculate the values for `document_validity` for every single day in the year (if I want users to make queries for any effective date in the year). By consequence, the table would be unavailable for a longer time.